# add Int to String

Tags: c, string, int

I'm trying to add an integer to a string. So it's something like this:

```
pass_value = m + ";" + v1 + ";" + v2 + ";" + v3 + ";" + v4
```

output would be:

```
2;23;21;53;34
```

But that doesn't work. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 5):

Integers and strings are two different types in C, and there is no way to add them, from your description, what you need is `sprintf` which will print the integers into a string buffer:

```
int m, v1, v2, v3, v4;
// do some computes for the integers
char str[512];
snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d", m, v1, v2, v3, v4);
printf("result is %s\n", str);
```